# Android recyclerview and sqlite issue

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I have existing db file and i want when user type word search in db after load it recyclerview. But when scroll up or down some times laggy. So i want to redesign it but i cant do this. When i use AsynTask in onBind to load in background sometimes my rows show empty...

DB file have three columns > **ID(Integer), Data(Text), Category(Text)**

Adapter;

```
public class AdapterSearch extends Adapter<MID, AdapterSearch.Holder> {

    public  AdapterSearch(Context context, List<MID> list) {
        super(context, list);
    }

    public void onBind(final Holder holder, final int pos) {
        final MData   mData     = Database.get(list.get(pos).id());
        if(mData.isValid()) {
            String textData     = mData.getData();
            String textCategory = mData.getCategory();

            holder.txData.setText(textData);
            holder.txCategory.setText(textCategory);
        }
    }

    public Holder createHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new Holder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_row, parent, false));
    }

    protected class Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @Nullable @Bind(R.id.data)
        AppCompatTextView txData;
        @Nullable @Bind(R.id.category)
        AppCompatTextView txCategory;

        public Holder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
        }
    }

}
```

MData;

```
public class MData {

    private String
            data,
            category;

    public MData(@Nullable String data, @NonNull String category) {
        this.data         = data;
        this.category          = category;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }


    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

}
```

MID;

```
public class MID {

    private final int
            id;

    public MID(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int id() {return this.id;}

}
```

Database;

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    ......

    public static MData get(int mID){
        MData mData = null;
        String   data;
        final Cursor cursor = db.query.....;
        if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            mData = new MData(cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
            cursor.close();
        }

        return mData;
    }

    ......
    ..

}
```

When search button click;

```
List<MID> searchList = null;
final Cursor cursorMID = db.query......;
if (cursorMID != null && cursorMID.moveToFirst()) {
    searchList = new ArrayList<>();
    do {
        searchList.add(new MID(cursorMID.getInt(0)));
    } while (cursorMID.moveToNext());
    cursorMID.close();
}

rcylerView.setAdapter(getContext(), searchList);
```